# Best way to convert state names in pig

Tags: string, apache-pig

I have data in hadoop that looks like this:

> DUMP EmailData; (Email, StateName) (allen@a.com, California)
>   (bobby@b.com, Arizona) (cindy@c.com, New York)
>
> DUMP StateData; (StateCode, Lon, Lat) (AZ, -111.93248, 34.17163) (NY,
>   -75.810280, 42.75633) (CA, -119.25700, 37.26842)

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
Locations = JOIN EmailData BY StateName, StateData BY StateCode;
```

But obviously you can't match names to codes. 
If it were SQL, I would either use case statements or define a table and insert values that can bridge the relationship I want.

What is the best way to do this in Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, fastest way would just be to quickly put together a 50-line (or more, depending on the presence of DC or any territories) file translating codes to names and `JOIN` it in. If you are feeling ambitious and don't want to deal with an extra file, you could write a UDF to do the translation, with the data hard-coded in. Since this data is very slow to change, hard-coding it is not a big deal.